# How to get py-scrypt's "simple password verifier" example functions to work?

Tags: python, scrypt

I am using the [example script](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/src) provide by `py-scrypt` to build a **simple password verifier**. Below is my test script.

**Test Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrypt
import os

def hash2_password(a_secret_message, password, maxtime=0.5, datalength=64):
    #return scrypt.encrypt(a_secret_message, password, maxtime=maxtime)
    return scrypt.encrypt(os.urandom(datalength), password, maxtime=maxtime)

def verify2_password(data, password, maxtime=0.5):
    try:
        secret_message = scrypt.decrypt(data, password, maxtime)
        print('\nDecrypted secret message:', secret_message)
        return True
    except scrypt.error:
        return False


password2 = 'Baymax'
secret_message2 = "Go Go"
data2 = hash2_password(secret_message2, password2, maxtime=0.1, datalength=64)
print('\nEncrypted secret message2:')
print(data2)

password_ok = verify2_password(data2, password2, maxtime=0.1)
print('\npassword_ok? :', password_ok)
```

**Issues:**
I often get an error messages, e.g.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/example_scrypt_v1.py", line 56, in <module>
    password_ok = verify2_password(data2, password2, maxtime=0.1)
  File "~/example_scrypt_v1.py", line 43, in verify2_password
    secret_message = scrypt.decrypt(data, password, maxtime)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrypt/scrypt.py", line 188, in decrypt
    return str(out_bytes, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

where the last lines varies to e.g.:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 3: invalid start byte
```

or

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

or no error message but return False

```
password_ok? : False
```

When I comment `return scrypt.encrypt(os.urandom(datalength), password, maxtime=maxtime)` to remove the random secret message generator and uncomment `return scrypt.encrypt(a_secret_message, password, maxtime=maxtime)` to use a non-random secret message, the function `verify2_password` works.

**Question:** How do I get the random secret message element to work?   What is causing it's failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation for UnicodeDecodeError Exception

### Reason 1

I think I understand why Scrypt is issuing a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Quoting [Python's UnicodeDecodeError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError) :

> The UnicodeDecodeError normally happens when decoding an str string
>   from a certain coding. Since codings map only a limited number of str
>   strings to unicode characters, an illegal sequence of str characters
>   will cause the coding-specific decode() to fail.

Also in [Python's Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html) section *Python’s Unicode Support --> The String Type*, it writes

> In addition, one can create a string using the decode() method of
>   bytes. This method takes an encoding argument, such as UTF-8, and
>   optionally an errors argument
>
> The errors argument specifies the response when the input string can’t
>   be converted according to the encoding’s rules. Legal values for this
>   argument are 'strict' (raise a UnicodeDecodeError exception),
>   'replace' (use U+FFFD, REPLACEMENT CHARACTER), 'ignore' (just leave
>   the character out of the Unicode result), or 'backslashreplace'
>   (inserts a \xNN escape sequence).

In short, whenever Python's `.decode()` method fails to map `str` strings to unicode characters, and when it uses the `strict` argument, the `.decode()` method will return a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception.

I tried to find the `.decode()` method in the [.decrypt()](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/src/a0801ed84b4e274d28edcfb547d52030bd5df331/scrypt/scrypt.py#scrypt.py-141) method of `py-scrypt/scrypt/scrypt.py`. Initially, I could not locate it. For Python3, the `.decrypt()` method  return statement was:
[return str(out_bytes, encoding)](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/src/a0801ed84b4e274d28edcfb547d52030bd5df331/scrypt/scrypt.py#scrypt.py-188)

However, further checking Python's explanation on the [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str) class, I found the explanation saying that:

> if object is a bytes (or bytearray) object, then str(bytes, encoding,
>   errors) is equivalent to bytes.decode(encoding, errors).

This meant that without defining the `error` argument in `str(bytes, encoding)`, this str class defaulted to returning `bytes.decode(encoding, errors='strict')` and returned the `UnicodeDecodeError` exception whenever it failed to map `str` strings to unicode characters.

### Reason 2

In the "simple password verifier" example, the `input` argument of Scrypt.encrypt() was defined as `os.urandom(datalength)` which returned a `<class 'bytes'>`.  When this `<class 'bytes'>` was encrypted, and subsequently decrypted by `Scrypt.decrypt()`, the returned decrypted value must also be a `<class 'bytes'>` . According to the doc_string of the [`.decrypt()` method](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/src/a0801ed84b4e274d28edcfb547d52030bd5df331/scrypt/scrypt.py#scrypt.py-141), for Python3 this method will return a str instance if encoded with encoding. If `encoding=None`, it will return a bytes instance. As `Script.decrypt()` defaults to `encoding='utf-8'` in function `verify2_password()`, `Script.decrypt()` attempts to return a `<class str>` resulted in the `UnicodeDecodeError`.

## Solution to the "simple password verifier" example script given in [py-scrypt](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/src/default/):

1. The `verify_password()` function should contain the argument `encoding=None` .
2. `scrypt.decrypt()` should contain the argument `encoding=encoding` .

**Revised Example Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrypt
import os

def encrypt_password(password, maxtime=0.5, datalength=64):
    passphrase = os.urandom(datalength)
    print('\npassphrase = ', passphrase, type(passphrase))
    return scrypt.encrypt(passphrase, password, maxtime=maxtime)

def verify_password(encrpyted_passphrase, password, maxtime=0.5, encoding=None):
    try:
        passphrase = scrypt.decrypt(encrpyted_passphrase, password, maxtime,
                                    encoding=encoding)
        print('\npassphrase = ', passphrase, type(passphrase))
        return True
    except scrypt.error:
        return False


password = 'Baymax'
encrypted_passphrase = encrypt_password(password, maxtime=0.5, datalength=64)
print('\nEncrypted PassPhrase:')
print(encrypted_passphrase)

password_ok = verify_password(encrypted_passphrase, password, maxtime=0.5)
print('\npassword_ok? :', password_ok)
```